# Creating generic method and using type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have created this method which is an object factory:

```
public static T GetService<T>(T serviceInterface)
{
    if (serviceInterface.Equals(typeof(IMemberService)))
    {
        return (T)(object)new MemberService();
    }
    else if (serviceInterface.Equals(typeof(ILookupService)))
    {
        return (T)(object)new LookupService();
    }
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("No action is defined for service interface " + serviceInterface.Name);
}
```

Now, I would like to go further and eliminate the need for "serviceInterface" parameter, but my problem is - I don't know how to compare type parameter T to an interface: doing

```
T.Equals(typeof(ILookupService))
```

gives compiler error: 'T' is a 'type parameter', which is not valid in the given context.

Any ideas how could I compare a type parameter to an interface?

Thank you,
Andrey

Comment: You can pick value from serviceInterface variable like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44114122/1580548

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `typeof(T)` to get a `Type` object back which could replace the use of `serviceInterface`

For example

```
public static T GetService<T>()
{
    Type serviceInterface = typeof(T);
    if (serviceInterface.Equals(typeof(IMemberService)))
    {
        return (T)(object)new MemberService();
    }
    else if (serviceInterface.Equals(typeof(ILookupService)))
    {
        return (T)(object)new LookupService();
    }
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("No action is defined for service interface " + serviceInterface.Name);
}
```

Comment: Damn, now I'm embarrassed! Soooo simple! Thanks a bunch Jared!

Comment: Sure, but will it ever equal an interface? If T represents the type of a concrete object, surely it won't equal an interface.

Comment: @spender, The GetService method can just as equally be invoked with an interface.  For example GetService<IFoo>();

Comment: OK agreed, but it gets smellier by the second

Comment: @spender, this is actually a well defined and used pattern in MEF.  `CompositionContainer` has this API and typically they are interface based.

Comment: To me it seems like a misappropriation of generics to start your generic method with checks for particular types/interfaces

Comment: @spender I thought you were complaining about the call site, not the actual code.  The actual code is also a common pattern though (think COM, or OLE IServiceProvider).  Perahps not a great one, but an existing established one.

Comment: @spender - what's wrong with my code in particular? What would you propose to change?

Comment: Andrey, there's probably nothing wrong. I just find it an unusual use of generics when the method branches according to the supplied generic type. In  this situation I'd simply create two non-generic methods of fixed type. I appreciate (from Jared's comments) that this may not suit your purposes.

Comment: I have to have one method - it's ultimately a service object factory, so I provide an interface and it will return a corresponding object. 
I figured that using generics in this case, even if unconventional, looks "nicer" in the code than returning an object and then casting to an interface

Answer (score 2):

Use `typeof(T)`.

So,

```
typeof(T).Equals(typeof(ILookupService))
```

Answer (score 1):

Could the [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator be applicable here?

Comment: `is` applies to *objects* not *classes*, so no, it wouldn't provide the OP with a solution. It could maybe be used in his original design, but not when removing the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (typeof(IMemberService).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
{}
else if (typeof(ILookupService).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
{}
```

Comment: Combine this answer (`IsAssignableFrom`) with JaredPar's answer, and you'll have the complete solution.

Comment: What's wrong with my original solution? I need to know if it the type passed matches exactly to the interface I compare to