# How can I access a static property of type T in a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to accomplish the following scenario that the generic TestClassWrapper will be able to access static properties of classes it is made of (they will all derive from TestClass). Something like:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static int x = 5;
}

public class TestClassWrapper<T> where T : TestClass
{
    public int test()
    {
        return T.x;
    }
}
```

Gives the error:

> 'T' is a 'type parameter', which is not valid in the given context.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure using static methods this way is supported.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can't, basically, at least not without reflection.

One option is to put a delegate in your constructor so that whoever creates an instance can specify how to get at it:

```
var wrapper = new TestClassWrapper<TestClass>(() => TestClass.x);
```

You could do it with reflection if necessary:

```
public class TestClassWrapper<T> where T : TestClass
{
    private static readonly FieldInfo field = typeof(T).GetField("x");

    public int test()
    {
        return (int) field.GetValue(null);
    }
}
```

(Add appropriate binding flags if necessary.)

This isn't great, but at least you only need to look up the field once...

Answer (score 8):

Surely you can just write this:

```
public int test() 
{ 
    return TestClass.x; 
}
```

Even in a nontrivial example, you can't override a static field so will always call it from your known base class.

Comment: This is pretty annoying that you can not have a virtual static field that can be overridden. My previous attempt was to use a static filed and static methods that use it and then I tried to derive from it and override the static field with other values, but it did't work.

Comment: @gw0 agreed that it's annoying, but I find the inability to do `T.StaticMethod()` less surprising seeing this answer; I don't find the inability to override static members surprising to begin with; I never considered polymorphism sans instances

Comment: @gw0 I know this is super old and you probably know this by now, but you can simulate overriding static properties by making them private fields and then accessing them through virtual properties that are not static. If the virtual property is accessing a static property then it is in effect static.

Comment: I don't know if this answer was ever right, but it is wrong.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier

Comment: @StefanBalan Using `new` is explicitly different from `override`, so it is correct that `you can't override a static field`. The `new` modifier _hides_ the matching member in the base class. It may be that for statics this is a distinction without a difference, but it still is distinct. It's also undeniable that a base class (or interface) cannot create a _contract_ specifying that a derived (implementing) class must define a certain static member (e.g. `public abstract BaseClass { public abstract static int x; }`). Which the OP appears to be after (or at least a simulacrum thereof).

Answer (score 6):

Generics do not support anything related to static members, so that won't work. My advice would be: don't make it static. Assuming the field genuinely relates to the specific `T`, you could also use reflection:

```
return (int) typeof(T).GetField("x").GetValue(null);
```

but I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just return `TestClass.x`?

Comment: I think this needs some unpacking, but is definitely the correct answer for the question as stated. To wit: as defined, `TestClassWrapper<T>` "knows" about `TestClass`. `TestClass.x` can be referenced through derived types, but they are all the same object. So if you want to know (or change) the value of `T.x` (if that were such a thing) it _fully suffices_ to define `public int test() => TestClass.x;`. There is a straight line to an implied question, which I'll cover in a separate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to simply *not* make it static, and work with the `new()` constraint on T to instantiate the object. Then you can work with an interface, and the wrapper can get the property out of any class that implements that interface:

```
public interface XExposer
{
    Int32 X { get; }
}

public class TestClass : XExposer
{
    public Int32 X { get { return 5;} }
}

public class XExposerWrapper<T> where T : XExposer, new()
{
    public Int32 X
    {
        get { return new T().X; }
    }
}
```

In fact, you can change that to `public static Int32 X` on the TestClassWrapper and simply get it out as `Int32 fetchedX = XExposerWrapper<TestClass>.X;`

Though since whatever code calls this will have to give the parameter T those same constraints, the wrapper class is pretty unnecessary at this point, since that calling code itself could also just execute `new T().X` and not bother with the wrapper.

Still, there are some interesting inheritance models where this kind of structure is useful. For example, an `abstract class SuperClass<T> where T : SuperClass<T>, new()` can both instantiate and return type T in its static functions, effectively allowing you to make inheritable static functions that adapt to the child classes (which would then need to be defined as `class ChildClass : SuperClass<ChildClass>`). By defining `protected abstract` functions / properties on the superclass, you can make functions that apply the same logic on any inherited object, but customized to that subclass according to its implementations of these abstracts. I use this for database classes where the table name and fetch query are implemented by the child class. Since the properties are protected, they are never exposed, either.

For example, on database classes, where the actual fetching logic is put in one central abstract class:

```
public abstract class DbClass<T> where T : DbClass<T>, new()
{
    protected abstract String FetchQuery { get; }

    protected abstract void Initialize(DatabaseRecord row);

    public static T FetchObject(DatabaseSession dbSession, Int32 key)
    {
        T obj = new T();
        DatabaseRecord record = dbSession.RetrieveRecord(obj.FetchQuery, key);
        obj.Initialize(record);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

And the implementation:

```
public class User : DbClass<User>
{
    public Int32 Key { get; private set;}
    public String FirstName { get; set;}
    public String LastName { get; set;}

    protected override String FetchQuery
    { get { return "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE KEY = {0}";} }

    protected override void Initialize(DatabaseRecord row)
    {
        this.Key = DbTools.SafeGetInt(row.GetField("KEY"));
        this.FirstName = DbTools.SafeGetString(row.GetField("FIRST_NAME"));
        this.LastName = DbTools.SafeGetString(row.GetField("LAST_NAME"));
    }
}
```

This can be used as:

```
User usr = User.FetchObject(dbSession, userKey);
```

This is a rather simplified example, but as you see, this system allows a static function from the parent class to be called on the child class, to return an object of the child class.

Comment: You can't just make code in dependencies 'not static'

Comment: Oh, this is just an exploration of possibilities in these things. Nothing explicitly said that the accessed static properties were in classed they couldn't edit though.

Answer (score 0):

T is a type, not parameter or variable so you cannot pick any value from any members. Here is a sample code.

```
public class UrlRecordService
{
    public virtual void SaveSlug<T>(T entity) where T : ISlugSupport
    {
        if (entity == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

        int entityId = entity.Id;
        string entityName = typeof(T).Name;
    }
}


public interface ISlugSupport
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `T` is a type, but so is `TestClass` in the OP's example. `TestClass.x` is perfectly valid, so why isn't `T.x` when `where T : TestClass` is specified?

Answer (score 0):

[cjk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7186512/85269) and [Haris Hasan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7186515/85269) have the most-correct answers to the question as asked. However in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186491/c-sharp-accessing-a-static-property-of-type-t-in-a-generic-class#comment8629388_7186512) the OP implies that he is after something else not quite possible in C#: a way to define a *contract* for a static member in a derived class.

There isn't a way to strictly define this, but it is possible to set up a pattern that may be implied by a base class (or interface); e.g.:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private static int x;

    public virtual int StaticX => x;
}
```

or if not intended to be used directly

```
public abstract class AbstractTestClass
{
    public abstract int StaticX {get;}
}
```

or (my preference in this contrived example)

```
public interface ITest
{
    int StaticX {get;}
}
```

Elsewhere, this pattern of a `StaticXxx` member may be (loosely) associated with implementations that should back the member with static fields (as in `TestClass` above).

What's kind of fun is that this *can* be (re)exposed as static by the generic wrapper, because generic statics are isolated to each type used.

```
public class TestClassWrapper<T> where T : ITest, new()
{
    private readonly static T testInstance = new T();

    public static int test() => testInstance.x;
}
```

This uses a `new()` condition, but an associated static, generic factory pattern for creating `ITest` (or `TestClass` or `AbstractTestClass`) instances may also be used.
However this may not be feasible if you can't have long-lived instances of the class.

Answer (score -1):

In this situation you assume that T is a subclass of TestClass. Subclasses of TestClass will not have the static int x.

Comment: I don't think this was ever true in any previous versions of  .NET. It is definitely not true now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier

Comment: This is wrong, but not because of `new`; more obviously, the static `TestClass.x` is  available through type-references to subclasses of `TestClass`—that is, `SubTestClass.x` will work. It's just the exact same `x`, which is different from what the OP wants.