# calling static method of Generic Type in c#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I am implementing **ISerializer** Interface, 
 in Deserialize method it access generic type 
which is ProtocolBuffer Class in my case  and here i have to Deserialize input string to protocolBuffer Class (Content)

but when i call Content.Parser.ParseFrom i get error saying

```
'Content' is type parameter which is not valid in given context;
```

i cant change Content class to fit my problem since it is generated using ProtoclBuffer Compiler for c# , also i cant change **ISerializer** since it is vendor library.

so what might be solution here ? how can i call **Content.Parser.ParseFrom** method

```
class PBFSerializer : ISerializer
    {

        public Content Deserialize<Content>(string json)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            return Content.Parser.ParseFrom(byteArray);
            //'Content' is type parameter which is not valid in given context;
        }

        public byte[] Serialize(object obj)
        {
                var content = (Content)obj;
                return content.ToByteArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# accessing a static property of type T in a generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186491/c-sharp-accessing-a-static-property-of-type-t-in-a-generic-class)

Comment: @MojtabaTajik , no , not really ,

Answer (score 0):

For you deserialization compile time error, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/message-parser#class_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_message_parser_1a0d6dd59d95463e0884cc7e168e12246f) told that **you should pass a** **Func** **as a function factory to create instances of** `T` **to the constructor of** `MessageParser<T>`.

It could `be () => new T()` or a more complicated function depending on what it's needed to create your messages.

Full code:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] buf) where T : IMessage<T>, new()
{
    if (buf == null)
        return default(T);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        MessageParser<T> parser = new MessageParser<T>(() => new T());
        return parser.ParseFrom(ms);
    }
}
```

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/interface/google/protobuf/i-message) says the serialization should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8358651/10189767) applies to your case (almost).  You can use reflection to invoke the static method  like this:

```
class PBFSerializer : ISerializer
{

    public T Deserialize<T>(string json) where T : someParentClass
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

        FieldInfo field = typeof(T).GetField(“Parser”);
        T result = field.FieldType.GetMethod(“ParseFrom”).Invoke(null, new object[]{byteArray});

        return result;
    }

    public byte[] Serialize<T>(object obj) where T : someParentClass
    {
            T content = (T)obj;

            return T.ToByteArray();
    }
}
```

You should also use a constraint on your type parameter like shown in the example since you’re calling a method that relies on your generic type being of a class that has a Parser property.  In your code snippet, “Content” is a generic type parameter, so I replaced it with T so that it’s not confused with meaning an actual class called “Content”.