# Is there a programming pattern to provide overrideable defaults for a generic class in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, factory

Suppose that I have a class `BaseClass` that has two child classes `ChildClassA : BaseClass` and `ChildClassB : BaseClass`. For each child class, I want to provide some implementation for two per-class constants, `Zero` and `One`, so that the following code would work:

```cs
var valueOfZeroA = ChildClassA.Zero;
var valueOfOneB = ChildClassB.Zero;
```

I should also be able to create a generic class that has a method that selects the appropriate value based on the generic type.

```cs
class GenericUsingClass<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        var valueOfZero = T.Zero;
        var valueOfOne = T.One;
    }
}
```

For instance, if I created a `new GenericUsingClass<ChildClassA>()`, then, the value of `valueOfZero` would be the same as `ChildClassA.Zero`.

**Here is my problem:** I need some programming pattern to implement something like this. I know that the syntax in my code examples will not be possible in the solution; it is just for illustrative purposes. I have provided a possible solution but I find it kind of ugly and am wondering if anyone can provide me with a better solution or explain why mine might be as good as it gets.

---

So far, I have come up with a factory pattern that seems like it would work decently. It goes as follows:

For each child class of `BaseClass`, there needs to be a factory class such as `ChildClassAFactory` and `ChildClassBFactory` each deriving from a class `BaseClassFactory`.

Then, `BaseClassFactory` would be defined as:

```cs
abstract class BaseClassFactory<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public abstract T Zero() { ... }
    public abstract T One() { ... }
}
```

and the child factories would implement the methods `Zero()` and `One()`.

The `GenericUsingClass` would have to then be refactored into:

```cs
class GenericUsingClass<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        BaseClassFactory<T> factory = new BaseClassFactory<T>();
        var valueOfZero = factory.Zero();
        var valueOfOne = factory.One();
    }
}
```

or alternatively, using dependency injection:

```cs
class GenericUsingClass<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public void DoStuff(BaseClassFactory<T> factory)
    {
        var valueOfZero = factory.Zero();
        var valueOfOne = factory.One();
    }
}
```

I dislike this approach because

1. It requires twice as many classes to implement the functionality of a single child class although this is my lesser concern.
2. I have to either create or inject an object factory in my generic using class which seems to add clutter to the code and make the implementation less easy to use.

I also know that reflection would be a possibility but it seems like overkill for this problem and would greatly messy things up. I'm just wondering what the best software architecture idea would be.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem your trying to solve?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you wantot to achieve? C# basically is a statically typed language and thus inheritance is in fact static. Or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# accessing a static property of type T in a generic class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186491/c-sharp-accessing-a-static-property-of-type-t-in-a-generic-class)

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. I've revised my question. I would be happy if you were to look at it again.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I have seen the method of using a static property and reflection but this seems messy and doesn't follow OOP principles very well which is the issue I'm running into.

Comment: @MatthewMiller it isn't clear why do you need this constaint `class GenericUsingClass<T> where T : BaseClassFactory<T>`, restrict `GenericUsingClass` type parameter to the factory class

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, you are correct. My apologies. Instead, I actually want the constain to be `class GenericUsingClass<T> where T : BaseClass` since I only want the generic using class to work with children of `BaseClass`. I've updated the samples.

Comment: As a possible and simple option you can restrict `T` to have a parameterless constructor `where T : BaseClass, new()`. Then you can create an instance like `var valueOfZero = new T();` If `BaseClass` has some properties, you can init them as well

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, this is a great idea. I will likely use it elsewhere in my project. Unfortunately, in my scenario, I consider `valueOfZero` and `valueOfOne` to be equally important and not necessarily numeric (of generic type as well) so a default constructor can't be used here; at least not for both constants.